# Column names in each view or function must be unique

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, view

while creating view I am getting error Column names in each view or function must be unique but while framing select query i am getting only one record.i  have to use col1 and col2 for both the tables..if data doesnot exist in A table it will take from B table.how i can do this.Thanks in advance..

```
Create View ViewName AS
select 
A.col1 as col1,
A.col2  as col2,
null as col1,
B.col2 as col2
from table A,table B where A.col3=B.col3
```

Comment: but i need have to use col1 and col2 for both the tables..if data doesnot exist in A table it will take from B table..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments, it looks like you are looking for this:

```
Create View ViewName AS
select 
   A.col1,
   COALESCE(A.col2, B.col2) AS col2
from table A
  left join table B 
  on  A.col3=B.col3;
```

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to handle the condition where the join fails.

*Explanation of the actual error:*

The error says it all - your view has two columns named `col1` and two columns `col2`. Change the columns names of one of the sets. Unlike views, an adhoc select query doesn't require unique names (or any column name at all, for that matter).

Comment: alter view temp as select COALESCE(A.col1,null,null,D.col1) as col1, COALESCE(A.col2,B.col2,C.col2,D.col2) as col2 from table A INNER JOIN table1 B INNER JOIN table3 C INNER JOIN table4 ON (A.col3=B.col3 and A.col3=C.col3 and A.col3=D.col3)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, you will probably need something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewName AS
SELECT ISNULL(A.col1, B.col1) as col1, -- This will return B.Col1 if A.Col1 is null
       ISNULL(A.col2, B.col2) as col2,
FROM table A INNER JOIN table B ON(A.col3 = B.col3)
```

### Edit

Based on your comments to this answer, you can do something like this:

```
ALTER VIEW temp AS 

SELECT COALESCE(A.col1, D.col1) as col1,
COALESCE(A.col2, B.col2, C.col2, D.col2) as col2 
FROM table A 
INNER JOIN table1 B ON (A.col3=B.col3)
INNER JOIN table3 C ON (A.col3=C.col3)
INNER JOIN table4 D ON (A.col3=D.col3)
```

Note: you wrote `COALESCE(A.col1,null,null,D.col1)`, this is equivalent to `COALESCE(A.col1, D.col1)`, since the [coalesce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function will return the first argument it receives that is not null.

Comment: what is the case if i have more than 2 tables?

Comment: Then use COALESCE. it can take more then 2 arguments. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: Like this..alter view temp as
select COALESCE(A.col1,null,null,D.col1) as col1,
COALESCE(A.col2,B.col2,C.col2,D.col2) as col2
from table A INNER JOIN table1 B INNER JOIN table3 C INNER JOIN table4 ON (A.col3=B.col3 and A.col3=C.col3 and A.col3=D.col3)

Comment: but it is  giving all combinations of records.JOIN is not working

Comment: can you provide some sample data and desired output?

Comment: i have to get single record..like if A tables contains data only that table data have to be shown and if B table contains data only that table data have to be shown and so on..but above query is showing all combinations of records including null

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired output. you can use this sql fiddle to provide the sample data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/caf818

Answer (score 1):

LIke this we can do?

```
alter view temp as select COALESCE(A.col1,null,null,D.col1) as col1, COALESCE(A.col2,B.col2,C.col2,D.col2) as col2 from table A INNER JOIN table1 B INNER JOIN table3 C INNER JOIN table4 ON (A.col3=B.col3 and A.col3=C.col3 and A.col3=D.col3)
```